# If no results found, display (message)

Tags: php, sql, error-handling, pear

Trying to display a message if no results found in the search query.

Here is a brief example of my code.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM details WHERE ID =1"

$res =& $db->query($sql);
if (PEAR::isError($res)) {
    die($res->getMessage());
}

while($row = $res->fetchRow())
{
     echo 'results'
    {
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DB_result` has a method called `numRows()`, so you could check

`if($res->numRows() == 0)`

http://pear.php.net/package/DB/docs/latest/DB/DB_result.html#methodnumRows

> Get the number of rows in a result set
>
> Return: the number of rows. A DB_Error object on failure.

And you don't need to worry about `DB_Error` since it was already checked at

`PEAR::isError($res)`